# python pickle object with lambdas

Tags: python-3.x, pickle, dill

How can I pickle a python object which contains lambdas?

```
Can't pickle local object 'BaseDiscretizer.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

is the error I get when trying to pickle https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/blob/97a1e2d7c1adf7b0c4f0d3b3e9b15f6197b75c5d/lime/discretize.py when pickling the https://github.com/marcotcr/lime/blob/2703bcdcddd135947fe74e99cc270aa4fac3263a/lime/lime_tabular.py#L88 LimeTabularExplainer

Comment: Lambdas can close over arbitrarily complicated pieces of context, up to the entire call stack. How could you pickle something like that?

Comment: And to answer my own comment: [by capturing the entire stack, of course!](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard `pickle` module cannot serialize lambdas, but there is a third party package called [`dill`](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill) which supports them.

Comment: thanks. `with open('data', 'wb') as f:
    dill.dump(exp, f)`works fine, however when reading it back: `with open('data', 'r') as f:
    dill.loads(f)` I get `a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.TextIOWrapper'
`

Comment: This is finally working: `with open('data', 'rb') as f:
    foo = dill.load(f)`