# Django channels 2 with selenium test failed

Tags: python, django, selenium, django-channels

I am trying to follow Django channels tutorial. I was able to implement chat functionality as discribed [here](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_3.html). But unittests completly copy pasted from this [page](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_4.html) failed with following error `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'DaphneProcess.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'`.

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\django_channels_test\venv35\lib\site-packages\django\test\testcases.py", line 202, in __call__
    self._pre_setup()
  File "C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\django_channels_test\venv35\lib\site-packages\channels\testing\live.py", line 42, in _pre_setup
    self._server_process.start()
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 105, in start
    self._popen = self._Popen(self)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 212, in _Popen
    return _default_context.get_context().Process._Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\multiprocessing\context.py", line 313, in _Popen
    return Popen(process_obj)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\multiprocessing\popen_spawn_win32.py", line 66, in __init__
    reduction.dump(process_obj, to_child)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\Lib\multiprocessing\reduction.py", line 59, in dump
    ForkingPickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'DaphneProcess.__init__.<locals>.<lambda>'
```

My consumer class:

```
class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
        self.room_name = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['room_name']
        self.room_group_name = 'chat_%s' % self.room_name

        # Join room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_add(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

        await self.accept()

    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        # Leave room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_discard(
            self.room_group_name,
            self.channel_name
        )

    # Receive message from WebSocket
    async def receive(self, text_data):
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        # Send message to room group
        await self.channel_layer.group_send(
            self.room_group_name,
            {
                'type': 'chat_message',
                'message': message
            }
        )

    # Receive message from room group
    async def chat_message(self, event):
        message = event['message']

        # Send message to WebSocket
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

My tests module:

```
from channels.testing import ChannelsLiveServerTestCase
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait


class ChatTests(ChannelsLiveServerTestCase):
    serve_static = True  # emulate StaticLiveServerTestCase

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        super().setUpClass()
        try:
            # NOTE: Requires "chromedriver" binary to be installed in $PATH
            cls.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        except:
            super().tearDownClass()
            raise

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super().tearDownClass()

    def test_when_chat_message_posted_then_seen_by_everyone_in_same_room(self):
        try:
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._open_new_window()
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._switch_to_window(0)
            self._post_message('hello')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                'Message was not received by window 1 from window 1')
            self._switch_to_window(1)
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                'Message was not received by window 2 from window 1')
        finally:
            self._close_all_new_windows()

    def test_when_chat_message_posted_then_not_seen_by_anyone_in_different_room(self):
        try:
            self._enter_chat_room('room_1')

            self._open_new_window()
            self._enter_chat_room('room_2')

            self._switch_to_window(0)
            self._post_message('hello')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                'hello' in self._chat_log_value,
                'Message was not received by window 1 from window 1')

            self._switch_to_window(1)
            self._post_message('world')
            WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
                'world' in self._chat_log_value,
                'Message was not received by window 2 from window 2')
            self.assertTrue('hello' not in self._chat_log_value,
                'Message was improperly received by window 2 from window 1')
        finally:
            self._close_all_new_windows()

    # === Utility ===

    def _enter_chat_room(self, room_name):
        self.driver.get(self.live_server_url + '/chat/')
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(room_name + '\n').perform()
        WebDriverWait(self.driver, 2).until(lambda _:
            room_name in self.driver.current_url)

    def _open_new_window(self):
        self.driver.execute_script('window.open("about:blank", "_blank");')
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])

    def _close_all_new_windows(self):
        while len(self.driver.window_handles) > 1:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[-1])
            self.driver.execute_script('window.close();')
        if len(self.driver.window_handles) == 1:
            self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[0])

    def _switch_to_window(self, window_index):
        self.driver.switch_to.window(self.driver.window_handles[window_index])

    def _post_message(self, message):
        ActionChains(self.driver).send_keys(message + '\n').perform()

    @property
    def _chat_log_value(self):
        return self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#chat-log').get_property('value')
```

I'm using Python 3.5 and Django 2.0.

Comment: reduction.py is trying to pickle a class with lambdas and is failing.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45715996/python-pickle-object-with-lambdas

Comment: @jinksPadlock Thanks for reply. It looks like package's bug, but I cannot find any reports about this error. So I think I just missed something.

Comment: I think it's a feature, not a bug. reduction.py is using pickle which can't serialize lambdas. I guess I would try removing the lambdas from your class to verify that they are the cause of the problem?

Comment: @jinksPadlock thank you for suggestion. I removed lambdas, but the error is still there.

Comment: Might be an issue with multiprocessing being buggy in Windows. This is not a real solution, but worth a check... In reduction.py you could replace `import pickle` with `import dill as pickle` Definitely not recommended for production but it could tell you if that's the problem.

Comment: @jinksPadlock Yes, after changes tests passed. Thank you very much! I didn't test it with linux yet but I believe it was indeed Windows related issue. Can you post an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`reduction.py` is failing to serialize objects containing lambdas. After a little research it seems that this is related to an issue with multiprocessing in a Windows environment (and is not limited to this example.)

One way to work around the issue is in `reduction.py`

replace: `import pickle` with `import dill as pickle`

The dill package can serialize these objects where pickle fails. However, I would not suggest this for a production environment without digging in to make sure this change doesn't break anything else.

Comment: I had the exact same issue as the above, we were both trying to follow the official docs tutorial. However when I try to change import pickle --> import dill as pickle in the reduction.py file I get the following error. 

django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.
I can provide the full trace if that would help.